# how to show, hide or change an element attribute when a controller async function resolves?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, watch, ng-show, ng-hide

i have some html elements, and they are hidden using `ng-hide`

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item class="ng-hide" ng-show="isLoggedin()" ng-click="login()">Login</ion-item>
        <ion-item class="ng-hide" ng-show="isLoggedin()" href="#/app/register">Register</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

in the controller i have a async function and when it resolves i would like to show those links

```
$scope.isLoggedin = function(){
    $scope.$on('some_function', function () {
        //this will resolve at some point
        return true;
    });
};
```

the idea is when `isLoggedin()` returns true, then the `ng-show` will be set to true as well.

im not set on using `ng-show="isLoggedin()"`, could be other solution, as long as it uses:

```
$scope.$on('some_function', function () {
    //this will resolve at some point
});
```

i could setup some `id's` and grab the elements and change the class in the controller, but i was thinking if there is a way to watch for the resolve and let the element know to show

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks pretty incomprehensible to me. For example returning true from event observer doesn't do anything at all, AFAIK. Also, don't manually set `class="ng-hide"` when using `ng-show` on the same element.

Anyway, if I understand it correctly, you just need to create a boolean property and set it after your asynchronous action completes:

```
$scope.$on('someEvent', function () {
    $scope.isLoadingFinished = true;
});
```

&

```
<item ng-show="isLoadingFinished">...</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the function `isLoggedIn()` try with a scoped variable, something like this

```
$scope.isLogged = false;
...
$scope.$on(....)
  $scope.isLogged = true;
....
```

and change your html to

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-if="isLogged" ng-click="login()">Login</ion-item>
    <ion-item ng-if="!isLogged" href="#/app/register">Register</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```